# Object passed in Intent from class FirebaseMessageReceiver not able to fetch in Activity

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, push-notification, android-pendingintent

On Receiving any push notification,
In class FirebaseMessageReceiver as usual We create Pending Intent, store data in it to pass it to out Activity.

I have done the same thing as below :

```
val intentPushNotification = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    intentPushNotification.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_BATTERY_ID, ""+firmwareObj.batteryId)
    intentPushNotification.putExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_FIRMWARE_OBJ,firmwareObj)
```

and Simply,
Receving it in HomeActivity as below :

```
val batteryId = intent.getStringExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_BATTERY_ID)
Log.e(">>>>> TEST ",""+batteryId)

val objFirmware = intent.getSerializableExtra(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_FIRMWARE_OBJ) as FirmwareUpdate
```

My **FirmwareUpdate** class is as below :

```
@Keep
data class FirmwareUpdate(
    val batteryId: String,
    val description: String,
    val firmwareUrl: FirmwareUrl,
    val id: Int,
    val timeStamp: Int,
    val versionNumber: String,
    val whatsNew: String
): Serializable
```

But the Issue is I am successfully fetch the value for **batteryId** and not for the
**firmwareObj**

I am getting null in it. What might be the issue?
And You can also check that I have implemented **:Serializable** also there in pojo class.

**ERROR :**

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.appview.home.model.downloadapi.FirmwareUpdate

Comment: Is `FirmwareUrl` also `Serializable`?

Comment: What do you do with the `PendingIntent` that you create? Are you putting that in a `Notification`?

Comment: I used bundle for it and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is that,
We can Create bundle,
Can add the serialisable object in Bundle and then We have to pass that Bundle inside Intent.

In this way, We can get access the object in our Activity from the Firebase notification class named : FirebaseMessageReceiver.